# $.ajax POST not working with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I'm using ESP32 as a web server, some values can be modified both web and micro side, in order to do this I use $.getJSON to retrieve data from the ESP32 and refresh the web page (everything works fine) and $.ajax to send data from web page to the server, also this part of the code works fine except for Safari, here is my code:

```
var data = {'name':'John','surname':'Smith'};
$.ajax({
        url: 'setConfig',           
        type: 'POST',   
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType:'json'
        });
```

My idea is that reading the url I understand which data is sending and 'data:' are the value of these variables. Using Google Chrome this is what I receive:

```
    POST /azzeraContatori HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://192.168.1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://192.168.1.1/contatori.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}
```

It's exactly what I want, but the same code using Safari browser:

```
    POST /azzeraContatori HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://192.168.1.1
Accept-Language: it-it
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Referer: http://192.168.1.1/contatori.html
Content-Length: 17
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

As you can see it's the same except for the missing 'data' at the begin of the message, I can't understand why this browser doesn't send this part of the $.ajax, if someone can help me I really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: in fact they both have same Content-Length: 17, so the data is possibly both sent properly. however i notice in chrome the data is encoded in gzip, where safari isnt. is the problem in fact related to how are you printing the request out?

Comment: The requests look the same, what about the responses?

Comment: @WilliamChong are printend in different order, but both has Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate.

Comment: @Musa forgive my lack but I don't know what do you mean with responses. The requests are processed by my program in C, but without data: JSON.stringify(data) I can't the informations that I need.

Comment: The Chrome example doesn't look right, either. The body of the request should be *after* the headers.

Comment: @WilliamChong `Accept-Encoding` doesn't say how the request is encoded, it's just giving permission for the server to encode the response. If the request were encoded there would be a `Content-Encoding` header.

Comment: How did you get these outputs. If they're coming from the browser console, I think you're just seeing differences in the way Chrome and Safari display requests.

Comment: @Barmar yeah read it wrong when the output was not edited with newlines, thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Barmar I agree with you, I can not even explain myself what I see. I simply printend what my micro received. I'm not I'm not very practical with the browser console so i use the micro side. But you think that the $.ajax function should work with Safari and the error is in the C code?

Comment: Something else is wrong. That JSON is 33 characters long, so `Content-length: 17` is too short.

Comment: Are you sure you're printing the correct header? Data is sent in the order Header 1, Data 1, Header 2, Data 2, ... it looks like you're showing the header of the next request after the data.

Comment: @Barmar ok I put order in the prints and I would say that now makes more sense, I edit the original post with the correct prints, let me know if there is something that I can do to fix the problem, or if you know some other equivalent method to achieve the same result.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `Content-length: 17` is still wrong, it should be `Content-length: 33`

Comment: @Barmar adding 'error: function()' of $.ajax request now the content.lenght is the correct number, and I see that any browser I use they display the error, so I think that Safari in case of error prevento to send data, instead Chrome send them in any case. How i can fix this problem? I just need that Safari send the field data in any case. Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I just created a simple web page containing nothing but jQuery and your Javascript. I opened the web console in Chrome and Safari, and they both showed it sending `Content-Length: 33` and the proper JSON as the request payload.

Comment: @Barmar do you use mobile device? Because I find out that this problem is only with Apple mobile device ( Iphone and Ipad ), it does not matter which browser you use ( Safari or Chrome ) the request payload won't be send. I don't know if it is a problem of Apple or exists a different way to do this, maybe use a .php file to save all the data.

Comment: No, I was testing with a Mac, I don't have an iOS device.